Unable to browse the simple ASP.NET Core 8 MVC web application

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MVCWebApp191.Controllers
{
    public class FirstController : Controller
    {
        public string GetName()
        {
            return "Vivek Anand";
        }
    }
}

I have created an ASP.NET Core 8 MVC web app and added the controller file and then modified the existing method to GetName() method that returns a string.
I'm getting this error:

How do I resolve this?

Please share the URL used. Meanwhile, from your screenshot, it just a warning for using HTTP protocol. You can still proceed by clicking the Advanced button and the link

What certificate did you use for the sight? If the answer is "I don't know" you're probably using .NET's development certificate. Normally, that certificate is added to the Trusted list when you first use the dotnet command. You can manage the dev certificate, recreate it or trust it with the dotnet dev-certs command. You can check if it's trusted with dotnet dev-certs https --check --trust or trust it directly with dev-certs https --trust

HI @PanagiotisKanavos, this is the output A trusted certificate was found: [ALPHANUMERIC] - CN=localhost - Valid from 2024-09-04 18:14:03Z to 2025-09-04 18:14:03Z - IsHttpsDevelopmentCertificate: true - IsExportable: true for this command dotnet dev-certs https --check --trust

After giving the command you provided, it is working fine @PanagiotisKanavos

For several reasons, please add the actual text of the error message in the question itself, not just a screeenshot. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors
